# GIT LFS over SSH?

Tags: git, ssh, git-lfs

Is it possible to do Git LFS over SSH?

I've read documentation and it seems git only does auth over SSH in LFS push. Here:

- https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/LFS-via-ssh/qaq-p/707647

they talk about how it is not supported

Comment: I think that link is out of date.  (And it is a 3rd party community forum question, not Git documentation!)  According to https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/main/docs/api/server-discovery.md LFS over SSH can be made to work, but it does require some configuration.

Answer (score 4):

[Brian M. Carlson](https://github.com/bk2204) added full SSH support to `git-lfs` in [version 3.0](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/pull/4446)!
So you should be able to upgrade `git` and the `git-lfs` plugin and you'll be good to go!

Thank you [@mstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/users/241453/mstrap)

Comment: This isn't correct anymore as of today: https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1044

Comment: Thank you! I'll correct my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, git LFS doesn't work to download LFS objects over ssh (i.e. `git clone myuser@myserver:path/to/repo.git`).

However, git LFS *does* work with locally-accessible directory-based clones (i.e. `git clone /path/to/myrepo` or `git clone /path/to/bare-repo.git`).

One possible solution is to mount the remote repository directory as a folder via, for example [SSHFS](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs), or Samba, or WebDAV, or any other networked file system driver. Then all you have to do is `git clone` it locally into your workspace.

Example using sshfs:

```bash
mkdir -p ~/.sshfs-mounts/mydevserver-testrepo
sshfs -o reconnect,idmap=user mydevserver:mygitrepos/testrepo ~/.sshfs-mounts/mydevserver-testrepo
git clone ~/.sshfs-mounts/mydevserver-testrepo ~/workspace/testrepo
```

Where:

- `mydevserver` is your server network name or IP
- `mygitrepos/testrepo` is the path relative to your home directory to your repo; `~/mygitrepos/testrepo/.git` on the remote server is the repo's git directory.
- `~/workspace/testrepo` is where you want to work on the files

Pushes/LFS "smudges" should work normally.